# Capacitorjs Sveltekit Adapter is not working

Tags: adapter, capacitor, sveltekit

I have a WebApp which fetches data from a database.
I have +server.js files from which my frontend fetches the data.

When I run `npm run build`:
adapter-auto:
No suitable adapter found.

adapter-static:

```
 @sveltejs/adapter-static: all routes must be fully prerenderable, but found the following routes that are dynamic:
    - src\routes

  You have the following options:
    - set the `fallback` option — see https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-static#spa-mode for more info.
    - add `export const prerender = true` to your root `+layout.js/.ts` or `+layout.server.js/.ts` file. This will try to prerender all pages.
    - add `export const prerender = true` to any `+server.js/ts` files that are not fetched by page `load` functions.

    - pass `strict: false` to `adapter-static` to ignore this error. Only do this if you are sure you don't need the routes in question in your final app, as they will be unavailable. See https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-static#strict for more info.

  If this doesn't help, you may need to use a different adapter. @sveltejs/adapter-static can only be used for sites that don't need a server for dynamic rendering, and can run on just a static file server.
  See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#prerender for more details
```

Answer (score -1):

I experienced the same problem. What worked for me is adding `export const prerender = true;` to my +layout.server.ts file. In your case, just add it to your +server.js file at the top and run the build command again.

You can learn more about prerendering in [SvelteKit docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#prerender)

Comment: should I include it into every server.js file or only the main? in routes>server.js?

Comment: @MxmlnHrc If you want every page to be prerendered, you only have to include it in the main server.js file